# How to Set "<options>" in fstab - Manual Mounting is Successfull

Tags: mount, network-shares, fstab

I am not real familiar with fstab yet, so I have a couple questions.  When I use this command to mount devices:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=admin //192.168.1.134/share_name /mnt/share_name
```

With passwords: sudo="local user password" password="password for device"

How do I translate that into an fstab entry?  So far, I have tried this in the fstab and mounting fails:

```
//192.168.1.134/share_name  /mnt/share_name  cifs  default  0  0
```

This is where the question comes in.  Where I have `default`, should there be something instead, indicating `username=admin`, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have something along the lines of:

```
//192.168.1.134/share_name /mnt/share_name cifs username=server_user,password=server_password,_netdev 0 0
^ Path to your share       ^ Mountpoint                  ^ Username           ^ Password      ^ See note A
```

Note A:
The `_netdev` options makes sure the mount is only attempted AFTER a network connection has been established.

Comment: cool, trying now - what is the `_netdev` piece?

Comment: @nocerellios see Note A in my answer.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `_netdev` option; it's very important for automatically mounting network drives.

Answer (score 2):

The ordering of an FSTab file is: `device name` `mount point` `fs-type` `options` `dump-freq` `pass-num`; each item separated by whitespace.

For the example you gave, the FSTab entry would be:

```
//192.168.1.134/share_name /mnt/share_name cifs username=admin,password=? 0 0
```

*(obviously replacing **?** with the correct password)*

If you want to learn more about FSTab, check out the [FSTab Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab).

Comment: Extra options can then be added such as the `_netdev` option suggested by BloodPhilia.